# Polymer paper-ripple programatically trigger downAction at given x,y coordinates

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to trigger a ripple animation programatically at a given x,y coordinate, but I can't seem to get it right.

I have found a few helpful answers like these:

1. [paper-ripple mouseDown event handler downAction Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060861/paper-ripple-mousedown-event-handler-downaction-override)
2. [Polymer paper ripple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668506/polymer-paper-ripple)
3. [How to trigger Polymer paper ripple animation by API code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277017/how-to-trigger-polymer-paper-ripple-animation-by-api-code)

I didn't find a way to apply the first two since at this stage I'm simply using a paper-ripple element without creating a custom element. The first answer is somewhat helpful, but I'd like to control the x,y coordinates of the ripple.

Here's how I tried to do this, using Jacek's snippet fro the 3rd answer:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <base href="https://polygit.org">
      <script src="/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="import" href="/components/polymer/polymer.html">
      <link rel="import" href="/components/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html">
      <style>
        .card {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          width: 300px;
          height: 240px;
          vertical-align: top;
          background-color: #fff;
          box-shadow: 0 12px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>      
      <template id="demo" is="dom-bind">
        <div class="card">
          <paper-ripple recenters></paper-ripple>
        </div>
      </template>
    </body>


    <script>
      var demo = document.querySelector('#demo');  
      
      var mouseDown = new MouseEvent("mouseDown",{"clientX":30,"clientY":30,"screenX":30,"screenY":30});
      var mouseUp = new MouseEvent("mouseUp",{"clientX":30,"clientY":30,"screenX":30,"screenY":30});
      
      demo.addEventListener('dom-change', function() {
        setInterval(triggerRippleDown, 1000);
        setInterval(triggerRippleUp, 1200);
      });
      
      var triggerRippleDown = function() {
        var paperRipple = document.querySelector('paper-ripple');
        paperRipple.downAction(mouseDown);
      }
      var triggerRippleUp = function() {
        var paperRipple = document.querySelector('paper-ripple');
        paperRipple.upAction(mouseUp);
      }
    </script>
    </html>
```

This passing x,y properties via mouse event doesn't seem to work, although this part of the documentation suggests so:

```
downAction: function(e) {
  this.$.ripple.downAction({x: e.x, y: e.y});
}
```

Any hints on what's the recommended way to trigger a ripple programatically outside of a custom component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know the recommended way but I have simple solution.
My solution is not to pass mouse event but object with x,y. look in this example:

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <base href="https://polygit.org">
      <script src="/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="import" href="/components/polymer/polymer.html">
      <link rel="import" href="/components/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html">
      <style>
        .card {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          width: 300px;
          height: 240px;
          vertical-align: top;
          background-color: #fff;
          box-shadow: 0 12px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>      
      <template id="demo" is="dom-bind">
        <div class="card">
          <paper-ripple recenters></paper-ripple>
        </div>
      </template>
    </body>


    <script>
      var demo = document.querySelector('#demo');  
      

     
      demo.addEventListener('dom-change', function() {
        setInterval(triggerRippleDown, 1000);
        setInterval(triggerRippleUp, 1200);
      });
      
      var triggerRippleDown = function() {
        
        var paperRipple = document.querySelector('paper-ripple');
       
       
        paperRipple.downAction({detail:{x:30,y:120}});
        console.log(paperRipple.xStart);
      }
   
      
      var triggerRippleUp = function() {
        var paperRipple = document.querySelector('paper-ripple');
       paperRipple.upAction();
      }
    </script>
    </html>
```

I use this and dont mouseEvent

```
  paperRipple.downAction({detail:{x:30,y:120}});

  paperRipple.upAction();
```

Comment: Thank you (+1). Much cleaner than what I've tried. Quick follow up: where did you spot the ```detail``` ? I haven't noticed that in the docs.

Comment: d'oh moment :) Thank you !

Comment: Also, fwiw, `upAction` takes no arguments.